# Outlook 14.0.7012.1000: no newline after special text

Tags: python, email, outlook, smtp

Try as i might, i can't get a linebreak after the x line in Outlook 14.0.7012.1000. Gmail and Outlook Web Access Light do correctly place the y line on its own.

```py
import smtplib

body = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx\r\nyyyyyyy"
text = "Subject: missing newline\r\n\r\n" + body

#from email.mime.text import MIMEText
#text = MIMEText(body).as_string()

s = smtplib.SMTP('exchange.company')
s.sendmail('', 'cees@company', text)
s.quit()
```

As the x (letter or space) pattern occurred in content i'm automatically sending emails about, i was wondering whether someone else ran into this and found a workaround short of using HTML email.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://oit2.utk.edu/helpdesk/kb/entry/465/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in Outlook, not in your email.

Turn off "*Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages*" in Outlook, and everything will be honkey-dorey.

Reference:

- http://oit2.utk.edu/helpdesk/kb/entry/465/